# Dual boot computer partitions missing after force shut down during hibernate

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, ssd, partition-recovery

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad Yoga 11s dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.  On computers where Ubuntu does not come preinstalled, the hibernate power option is disabled because problems can happen. I enabled the power option after doing a basic check that it would work. Maybe the tenth time using this feature, the computer was taking about a half hour to hibernate. I had to go, so I force shut it down with the power button. The next time I went to boot the computer, it gave the error message "No bootable device found, please insert bootable device." Grub seems to work fine, and when I run SMART from the command line of a live Ubuntu usb, it says the health status of /dev/sda is okay, although it fails the "scsi sanity test." When I run Disks from the application center, all of the options for /dev/sda are greyed out.

I cannot use the factory reset option in Windows because I cannot access that operating system. The system recovery partition is also not accessible by my computer right now.

In BIOS there is an option for "system recovery," but when I select it, I get the same error message.

When I used an Ubuntu 18.04 live usb after this, the computer booted fine, but the partitions where Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 are stored (/dev/sda*) do not show up in GParted. The computer also tells me that I only have 8 GB free on the SSD so that I cannot install Ubuntu 18.04.

I tried using dban to wipe the hard drive so that I could just do a clean install of whatever operating system, but it "exits with non-fatal errors" without doing anything. I looked on the dban site, and apparently it does not work with SSDs.

Now, I would like to use hdparm's ATA secure erase or something similar, but since /dev/sda does not show up in GParted, I cannot use the command.

Any way to recover the old operating systems or reclaim my missing SSD space so that I can install an operating system again would be greatly appreciated.

TLDR: Force shut down computer during hibernate, now it won't boot into the operating system.